# How to access existing graphs in arcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, data, arcgis-9.3, tools

I am trying to access an existing graph in arcGIS version 10.  The student workbook I am using was written for version 9.3.  Version 10 does not have "tools" option in the toolbar. The instructions guide students to the 'Tools' option.
I will be teaching students to use arcGIS using 'Mapping our World' student workbooks (written for version 9.3) using version 10.

Answer (score 1):

The [Graph Manager](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00330000002z000000) is now found under **View|Graphs>Manage Graphs**.